# Why can't I print the value from input type using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is a very simple application that lets the user change his name. However, there is some bug in this code.  Whenever the user writes something into input, the change is not reflected in the welcome header.

app.js

```
'use strict';

angular
  .module('angularScopesBug', [])
  .controller("WelcomeController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'John Doe';

    $scope.getName = function() {
      return $scope.name;
    };
  })
  .controller("EditingController", function($scope) {
    $scope.editMode = false;
    $scope.changeName = function() {
      $scope.editMode = true;
    };
    $scope.closeEditor = function() {
      $scope.editMode = false;
    };
  })
  .directive("nameEditor", function () {
    return {
      template: 'Write your name: <input type="text" ng-model="name">'
    };
  });
```

index.html

```
<div ng-app="angularScopesBug" ng-controller="WelcomeController">
  <h1>Hello, {{ getName() }}</h1>
  <div ng-controller="EditingController">
    <button ng-click="changeName()" ng-show="!editMode">Change your name</button>

    <div ng-show="editMode">
      <name-editor ng-show="editMode"></name-editor>
      <button ng-click="closeEditor()" ng-show="editMode">Close name editor</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The header should change according to the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use an object in `ng-model`.

Primitives have no inheritance and the nested controller is using a child scope. When that child scope is created it gets the primitive `name` as value.

When it is an object the object is inherited so that updating property values will be reflected in all references to that object

```js
angular
  .module('angularScopesBug', [])
  .controller("WelcomeController", function($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
      name: 'John Doe'
    };      
  })
  .controller("EditingController", function($scope) {
     // simplified for clarity
  })
  .directive("nameEditor", function() {
    return {
      template: 'Write your name: <input type="text" ng-model="model.name">'
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" ></script>


<div ng-app="angularScopesBug" ng-controller="WelcomeController">
  <h1>Hello, {{ model.name }}</h1>
  <div ng-controller="EditingController">
    <button ng-click="editMode = true" ng-show="!editMode">Change your name</button>

    <div ng-show="editMode">
      <name-editor ng-show="editMode"></name-editor>
      <button ng-click="editMode = false" ng-show="editMode">Close name editor</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your two controllers have different $scope values. Since the editor is inside the EditingController $scope, it is changing a .name value in the lower scope, not in the higher WelcomeController $scope.

Try giving yourself a parent method to modify the value;

```
$scope.changeName = function(str) {
    $scope.name = str;
};
```

And then calling that method with the new name from the child.

Comment: so you think i should write the getName() in EditingController?

Comment: The real problem is that the parent scope is calling it's parent .name, but the child is setting it's child .name. Have the child pass a value into the parent as a primitive.